# Custom axis breaks in ggplot2 facets based on other columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have data to plot, where the x-axis is found in one column, and the x-axis major breaks are found in other columns.

For my sample data, I will modify the `iris` dataset from `ggplot2`.  Note: the `low` and `high` are arbitrarily calculated here - I've only chosen min & max for ease of reproducibility.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


df <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(low = min(Sepal.Length),
         high = max(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

```
> df
# A tibble: 150 x 7
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   low  high
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa    4.3   5.8
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa    4.3   5.8
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa    4.3   5.8
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa    4.3   5.8
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa    4.3   5.8
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa    4.3   5.8
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa    4.3   5.8
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa    4.3   5.8
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa    4.3   5.8
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa    4.3   5.8
# ... with 140 more rows
```

I am hoping to plot `x = Sepal.Length` faceting for `Species`, but with the only two major breaks being `df$min` and `df$max`.

I'm having trouble getting the breaks in the correct facet.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length,
             y = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(. ~ Species) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(df$low, df$high))
```

[image]

As you can see, the values from `df$low` and `df$high` applied to all facets.  I was hoping that facet `setosa` would only have major breaks at 4.3 and 5.8 only, `versicolor` at 4.9 and 7.0 only, and `virginica` at 4.9 and 7.9 only.

Is there a way to pass the facet variable to `breaks` in `scale_x_continuous`?  Or should I abandon this approach and create three separate ggplots and merge them together with `gridExtra`?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does it help to add scales = "free" into the facet_wrap call?

Comment: I've tried `scales = "free"`, but it does not work where there are overlaps between ranges (e.g. `setosa` shows 4.3, 4.9, and 5.8 - the 4.9 is supposed to be associated with `versicolor`)

Comment: Your `mutate` isn't working. Since mutate is in both plyr and dplyr you need to specify which one you want. 
`df <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(low = min(Sepal.Length),
         high = max(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  ungroup()`


`df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length,
             y = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(. ~ Species,scales = "free") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(df$low, df$high))`

Comment: @Tanner33 I believe you may have previously loaded in `plyr` in your own session.  In my code, I've only called `dplyr`.  You can resolve this on your end by calling `dplyr::mutate`

Comment: @DaveGruenewald You are correct that I had plyr loaded in my session. I was guessing that was your problem because I was able to replicate your results by doing so. When I specified dplyr in the code in my previous comment the results appeared to be what you were looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not resolve my issue as explained in my previous comment to @JordanHackett

Comment: @DaveGruenewald There does not seem to be a straightforward way to do this. I found a post that does specify a slightly convoluted way of doing it: https://fishandwhistle.net/post/2018/modifying-facet-scales-in-ggplot2/

Comment: @DaveGruenewald you are correct. I see the issue now and apologize for my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using [patchwork](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(patchwork)

df %>% 
  split(.$Species) %>% 
  map(~{
    .x %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length,
                 y = Petal.Length)) + 
        geom_point() + 
        facet_wrap(~ Species) + 
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(max(.x$low), max(.x$high))) +
        # assuming you want to use same y axis for each plot
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(df$Petal.Length), max(df$Petal.Length)))
  }) %>% 
  reduce(`+`)
```

[image]

I think this is the easiest way that doesn't involve messing with `ggproto`

Comment: nice. another option is to use `df %>% 
    group_split(Species) %>% ...`

Comment: @Tjebo it doesn't matter at all in this case but I'm not a fan of `group_split` returning an unnamed list

Comment: that’s true and I totally agree.

Answer (score 1):

The break arguments to scales don't support tidy evaluation in the context of the data.frame passed to the main ggplot2 call. If your breaks can be calculated from the facet limits (typically the data limits + expansion, when `scales = "free"`), you can pass a function to the breaks argument that calculates the breaks from the limits.

If you are really set on having seperate scales per facet, there are a few packages on github that support providing custom scales to facets of a plot. Both require you to specify a scale for each facet manually. Disclaimer: I've contributed to the first package and am author of the second package.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)


df <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(low = min(Sepal.Length),
         high = max(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# Forgive the clunky tidyverse syntax
scale_list <- df$Species %>% levels() %>% setNames(.,.) %>% lapply(., function(i) {
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(unlist(df[df$Species == i, c("low", "high")])))
})

#devtools::install_github("zeehio/facetscales")
library(facetscales)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length,
             y = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid_sc(cols = vars(Species), scales = list(x = scale_list))
```

[image]

```r
#devtools::install_github("teunbrand/ggnomics")
library(ggnomics)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length,
             y = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(. ~ Species, scales = "free_x") +
  facetted_pos_scales(x = scale_list)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>